# Creating a new user is AD that has the same first and last name of a current user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a situation that it seems like the AD-NewUser command is failing due to the same first and surname existing.  I am not sure what else it will be as the output of a log shows that we are generating a unique samAccountName correctly.

```
 New-ADUser -Name "$FirstName $SurName" -givenName $FirstName -Surname $SurName -displayName "$FirstName $SurName" -samAccountName $SAMAccountLower
```

Here are the two log outputs.  As you can see the username is unique in the second instance, but the first and last name are identical.

First attempt:

```
Initialising log
Beginning username hunt
Username is tinkert
Beginning AD work
Beginning Exchange work
Done
```

Second attempt:

```
Initialising log
Beginning username hunt
Username is tinkerte
Beginning AD work
An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name that is already in use
Done
```

Not sure what to put in there to force AD to accept a new user with identical first and last name but a unique samAccountName - is this even possible?

thanks

Comment: `Name` just can't be duplicated in the same OU, simply like 2 files can't be the same name in the directory. Some choose to append a number, some use `sAMAccountName` instead. Just a choice, no big deal.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did some scratching around and found way back when we had done what you said.. basically chucked a number at the end.